# I can't use third party js with angular js and ASP.NET MVC

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc, angularjs-injector, angular-route-segment

Hello I am creating application with ASP.NET MVC and Angular js.

Everything is running fine but when I want to use any third party js for angular js it is not allowing to do ...

I have created three js files.

1) **app.js**

```
var app;
(function () {
    app = angular.module("ANG", []);

    app.factory('GlobalService', function () {
        return {
            urlBase: 'myserviceurl/',
            UserName: '',
            UserRole: ''
        };
    });
})();
```

2) **Controller.js**

```
   app.controller("CustomerCtrl", ["$scope", "$q", "VendorService", "CustomerService", "$filter", function ($scope, $q, vendorService, customerService, $filter){
       //My code here
}
]);
```

3) **Service.js**

```
app.service('VendorService', ["$http", "$q", "GlobalService", function ($http, $q, globalService) {
//My service calling
}]);
```

4) **Implemented in View**

```
<html lang="en" id="htmlMainPage" ng-app="ANG">
```

I want to use [multiselection](http://dotansimha.github.io/angularjs-dropdown-multiselect/docs/#/main) js to implement multiselection dropdownlist.

I have done below one line change only and in controller and view further changes.

**app.js**

```
app = angular.module("ANG", ["angularjs-dropdown-multiselect"]);
```

It's running fine as well but other pages who has also use this app.js giving me an error.

[image]

Comment: Where you have give reference of the multiselect js?

Comment: In the view page I mean where I needed in the page only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just look into the reference of the js you have given.

You have to give reference or add multiselect.js in the layout page because as you have told in the question how you implemented the app.js.

```
<html lang="en" id="htmlMainPage" ng-app="ANG">
```

It will call every time when any view load and find for the multiselect.js reference and gives you the injector error and will not go further.

Refer: [Angular injector error](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=ANG&p1=Error:%20%5B$injector:modulerr%5D%20http:%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.6.1%2F$injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dangularjs-dropdown-multiselect%26p1%3DError%253A%2520%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.1%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dangularjs-dropdown-multiselect%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A14%253A425%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A33%253A399%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520b%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A32%253A439)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A33%253A173%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A49%253A117%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A15%253A351)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A48%253A488)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A49%253A134%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520q%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A15%253A351)%250A%2520%2520%2520%2520at%2520g%2520(http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A49685%252Fbundles%252Fangular%253Fv%253DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1%253A48%253A488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:14:425%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:49:392%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:15:351)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:48:488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:49:134%0A%20%20%20%20at%20q%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:15:351)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20g%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:48:488)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20eb%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:53:56)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20c%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:29:19)%0A%20%20%20%20at%20Mc%20(http:%2F%2Flocalhost:49685%2Fbundles%2Fangular%3Fv%3DmeYDSQ-UahfYcbhySzS7P4PWI0w3PQrLaTDYaFcQOEY1:29:332)

Comment: Ohh yes I add multiple.js in the layout and it's running now. thanks.

Comment: You are welcome. Make sure that when you use any third party js in angular js put that in the layout if you are using the app.js where you have implemented module once only and if you using different js (app.js for module) for every page than just give reference on that view only.